# Printing out strings from a file after newline

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I'm trying to output contents of my text file as strings to the console but I am not getting the desired output. I tried implementing the following but still no luck, any help would be appreciated.

```
int main() {
     ifstream inFile("src/text.rtf");
     string line;

     while (getline(inFile, line)) {
         cout << line << endl;
     }
     return 0;
 }

Text contents:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Output:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1344\cocoasubrtf720
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\    tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 1\
2\
3\
4\
5\
6}
```

Comment: Your file is not a plain text file. It is an [RTF (rich text format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file. It contains more than just the text that you entered, it contains formatting information for how the text looks in a word processing program. The code you used to print the lines of a file is correct, but `getline` is not going to automatically parse the rtf file for you and only give you the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `inFile` file is not a 'pure' text file, but with the formatting code of [Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).

Please use notepad.exe to create your `inFile`